# GIT how to delete branch if remote missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I have a Rails app that I deployed to Heroku for testing.
I deleted the Heroku version of the app from the Heroku site.

Now, I'm trying to delete the Heroku git branch from my local development and it won't let me because it can't logon to the deleted Heroku app/git.

How can I delete the Heroku git branch?

Thanks!

Comment: what git command have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remote tracking branches, the branches that appear in `git branch -r` with names like `heroku/master`, are deleted when you delete the remote they belong to:

```
git remote rm heroku
```

(Where "heroku" is the name of the remote you were using to push to heroku.)

If you have local branches that you want to get rid of, as well, you can delete those normally with `git branch -d` (which only succeeds if the branch is already merged in) and `git branch -D` (which works if it isn't).